# ForeignKeyConstraint not working

Tags: xml, dataset

In my code, I tried `foreignkeyconstraint`, but it's not working (ie it doesn't throw an error when I delete a row which is related to another table).

Please let me know what is the issue with the following code:

```
try
        {
            int salesid = 2;


            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

            DataSet fakeDS = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = null;
            fakeDS.ReadXml(@"product.xml");

            dt = fakeDS.Tables[0].Copy();
            dt.TableName = "product";
            ds1.Tables.Add(dt);

            DataSet fakeDS2 = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt2 = null;

            fakeDS2.ReadXml(@"sales.xml");

            dt2 = fakeDS2.Tables[0].Copy();
            dt2.TableName = "sales";
            ds1.Tables.Add(dt2);

            DataColumn dcParent, dcChild;

            dcChild = ds1.Tables["sales"].Columns["productid"];
            dcParent = ds1.Tables["product"].Columns["id"];

            ForeignKeyConstraint FKC = new ForeignKeyConstraint("foreignkeys", ds1.Tables["product"].Columns["id"], ds1.Tables["sales"].Columns["productid"]);
            FKC.DeleteRule = Rule.None;
            ds1.Tables[1].Constraints.Add(FKC);
            ds1.Tables[1].AcceptChanges();
            ds1.AcceptChanges();


            for (int i = 0; i < ds1.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ds1.Tables[1].Rows[i]["salesid"].Equals(salesid.ToString()))
                //if (ds1.Rows[i]["productid"].Equals(salesid.ToString()))
                {
                    //dt2.Rows[i].Delete();

                    ds1.Tables[1].Rows[i].Delete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add ForeignKeyConstraint between the table that means you can not delete data from the parent table if child table exists this code, if you delete like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds1.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["productid"].Equals(salesid.ToString()))
                    //if (ds1.Rows[i]["productid"].Equals(salesid.ToString()))
                    {
                        //dt2.Rows[i].Delete();

                        ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i].Delete();
                    }
                }
                ds1.AcceptChanges();
```

its show you a exception

```
"Cannot delete this row because constraints are enforced on relation foreignkeys, and deleting this row will strand child rows."
```

So in that case, **First** to you remove the data from the child table and then **Second** you have to remove the data from the parent table,

But its not possible if you remove the data from child table then its automatically remove the data from the parent table.

Comment: what error message is coming, I have tried at my end and its works fine, could you please give me more detail?

Comment: The issue is :foreign key constrain not firing when i tried to delete a row (which belongs to parent table data) (you can see in the code)

Comment: Thanks again for replying,sorry ,i have not understood,pls explain me in detail